# Thymeleaf th:textappend does not work

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have this piece of code in my Thymeleaf template but I don't see the text "online" that I'm appending at the end of the tag.

```
<td class="col_name" 
  th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(bedPriceSummary.weeklyMinPrice, 0, 'DEFAULT', 2, 'DEFAULT')} + ' &euro;' " th:textappend="'online'">
</td>
```

Comment: Note: you could probably use the much simpler: `#numbers.formatCurrency(bedPriceSummary.weeklyMinPrice)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`th:textappend` is not supported, refer the [doc](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#appending-and-prepending)

> There are also two specific appending attributes in the Standard
>   Dialect: the th:classappend and th:styleappend attributes

Use `th:classappend="'online'"` instead.